# Save the created by, updated by and deleted by information

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to save the information in each of my tables about the creation, the update or the delete of a record.

Currently I have the following:

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, index=True)
    
    civil_title = Column(Enum(EnumTitle))
    lastname = Column(String, index=True)
    firstname = Column(String)
    type = Column(Enum(EnumTypeUser))

    hashed_password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    is_active = Column(Boolean(), default=True)
    is_superuser = Column(Boolean(), default=False)

    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=False),server_default=func.now(), nullable=False)
    created_by = Column(UUID, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    created_by_rl = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[created_by])
    updated_at = Column(DateTime)
    updated_by = Column(UUID, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    updated_by_rl = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[updated_by])
    deleted_at = Column(DateTime)
    deleted_by = Column(UUID, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    deleted_by_rl = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[deleted_by])
    practice_id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey("practice.id"))
    practice = relationship("Practice", foreign_keys=[practice_id], back_populates="employees")

    address_id =  Column(UUID, ForeignKey("user_address.id"))
    address = relationship("UserAddress",foreign_keys=[address_id], back_populates="users")
    # items = relationship("Item", back_populates="owner")

    contacts = relationship("UserContactDetail", back_populates="user")

    schedules = relationship("Schedule", back_populates="user")

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity":"user",
        "polymorphic_on":type
    }
```

And

```py
class UserAddress(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_address"

    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, index=True)
    
    street = Column(String)
    streetnumber = Column(String)
    town = Column(String)
    cp = Column(Integer)

    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=False),server_default=func.now(), nullable=False)
    created_by = Column(UUID, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    created_by_rl = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[created_by])
    updated_at = Column(DateTime)
    updated_by = Column(UUID, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    updated_by_rl = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[updated_by])
    deleted_at = Column(DateTime)
    deleted_by = Column(UUID, ForeignKey("user.id"))
    deleted_by_rl = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[deleted_by])

    users = relationship("User", back_populates="address")
```

I'm having the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'user_address' and 'user'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.
```

How can I make sure this error does not happen?
Is it a good practice to do such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the wrongly defined relationships to all these columns, that is the reason for that error. To solve your problem I would try something like this:

```py
class TrackTimeMixin:

    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())

    updated_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=datetime.now)

class SoftDeleteMixin:
    deleted_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)

    def soft_delete(self):
        self.deleted_at = datetime.now()


class User(Base, TrackTimeMixin, SoftDeleteMixin):
    """define other columns"""

class UserAddress(Base, TrackTimeMixin, SoftDeleteMixin):
    """define other columns"""
```

`TrackTimeMixin` is used for `created_at` and `updated_at` columns and it should
work automatically.

`SoftDeleteMixin` adds `deleted_at` column, and you will need to add a bit more logic to make it works.

I've itentionally split this into 2 mixins cause for some other models, you might want to use only one or none of them. So now, when you want to delete an user you instead of doing this:

```py
session.delete(user)
session.commit()
```

You will actualy do this:

```py
user.soft_delete()
session.commit()
```

You will also need a logic to fetch not deleted users but implementation of that should be easy from this point.

Comment: And I should use the very same Mixins in order to save the user information associated with the creation, update and deletion?

Comment: Right, you can add this mixins in any model you need, these columns will be then added to other columns of that model. Information will be automatically saved for `created_at` and `updated_at` while for `deleted_at` you will have to use `soft_delete` method

Comment: I used your answer along the one provided at for the user foreign keys, using the `@declared_attr` flag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183012/sqlalchemy-mixin-foreignkey-and-relation. Thanks!